# What is the different between system and Administrator account when call SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I write two program, one is windows service run in system account(named xxService)  and the other one is common application run in Administrator account(named xx);

They use the same code to get `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` directory.  In most machine , they run well.

But some machine, the xxService can get the correct directory,  the xx have failure in `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()`;

edit:
the program only run on Windows XP(sp3).

edit2:
Use `SHGetFolderPathA()` function to solve this problem.

My english is poor, everybody excuse me!

log:

```
[2964] [db](tid=1108)(pid=2964): SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() fail.hr=0x80070057, ierr=122
```

the detail error info:

```
//
// MessageId: E_INVALIDARG
//
// MessageText:
//
// One or more arguments are invalid
//
#define E_INVALIDARG _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80070057L)
```

```
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
122 (0x7A)
The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

code:

```
 //C:\Users\Public\Documents
 LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
 LPMALLOC pShellMalloc;
 HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
 hr = SHGetMalloc(&pShellMalloc);
 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
     hr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL,CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS,&pidl);
     if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
     {
         if(!SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidl, strDbFilePath))
         {
             int ierr=GetLastError();
             DebugMsgW((L"SHGetPathFromIDListW() fail., ierr=%d"), ierr);
         }
         DebugMsgW(L"DBpath=%s",strDbFilePath);
         pShellMalloc->Free(pidl);
     }
     else
     {
         int ierr=GetLastError();
         DebugMsgW((L"SHGetSpecialFolderLocation() fail.hr=0x%x, ierr=%d"), hr, ierr);
     }
     pShellMalloc->Release();
 }
 else
 {
     int ierr=GetLastError();
     DebugMsgW((L"SHGetMalloc() fail.hr=0x%x, ierr=%d"), hr, ierr);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()` (and any other function that returns an HRESULT) does not use `GetLastError()` to report error codes, since the `HRESULT` *is* the error code. Even `SHGetPathFromIDList()` is not documented as using `GetLastError()`, either.  So the return value of `GetLastError()` is irrelevant in your example and needs to be removed to avoid confusion.

As for the `E_INVALIDARG` error, you are using a legacy function.  `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` [is known to fail in `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()`](http://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/ioQmeh56/csidl-common-documents-returns-e-invalidarg-on-xp) on some systems.  You need to use a newer function, such as [`SHGetFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx), or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) on Vista+.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the program only run in xp(sp3) system. Clearly there is another problem here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use SHGetFolderPathA() to get directory, It does solve this problem.